# How can I use a controller (designed for PlayStation) on a PC, with Xbox layout?

Tags: pc, controllers

I just bought a controller for use on my PC, but turns out it's not an 'Xbox type' controller. It seems to be a controller with a layout for PlayStation, so when I play games with controller support the controls are all weird.

I can't find a way to re-map my controller in the Windows Control panel, and I'd like to avoid buying additional hardware if I can help it (such as adapters). Is there a utility that will enable me to remap the buttons?

Comment: This may get better traction on SuperUser.

Comment: Mhh.... try x360ce - It's a controller emulator. I think you can rebind the buttons... It's free, so worth a shot.

Comment: What do you mean by "all weird"?

Comment: Is it an actual Playstation controller? Seconding the need to explain what's "weird" about the controls.

Answer (score 2):

[MotioninJoy](http://www.motioninjoy.com/wiki/en/help). It's a driver meant to take input from a Dualshock3 or Dualshock2 controller as if it was an Xbox 360 controller. It works flawlessly with most USB-controllers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most games that support controllers allow you to set the settings ingame. If you are using emulation software, you have the option there to change the mapping.

As replied by kotekzot: What do you mean with "all weird"? The X acts as the O?

Answer (score 0):

Xpadder, the latest version is not free. However I was able to find outdated versions on cnet (or some other site of its ilk) and use it with no problems.

It allows you to set up any and all custom mapping for controllers. You set up your controller layout, then assign buttons to key/mouse controls. Super easy, super effective. It even allows for macros to be setup, toggle functions, vibration settings, turbo thingy... It really is amazing.